# Cause .net WCF client to use RPC/encoded instead of Document/Literal/Wrapped with Delphi service

Tags: .net, wcf, delphi, interop, rpc

I have a .Net WCF client/proxy built based on a Delphi service.  The Delphi service is providing SOAP messages in a format that my client has been unable to process.

Based on the guidance here: [Delphi SOAP Envelope and WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473051/delphi-soap-envelope-and-wcf) I've come to understand that WCF expects "Document/Literal/Wrapped" style to be the way in which the message is serialized.  As it turns out, the Delphi service is using "rpc" as the style.

I cannot get the delphi service to change its style.

Is there a way I can tell the WCF client to use "rpc" instead.

For reference, here's the Delphi service I'm building against: http://www.tntschools.com/AkiTimeTableService/wsdl/ICourses

Comment: How did you create client/proxy? Via `Add Service Reference` or you have built it manually?

Comment: I used "Add Service Reference" to build it.

Comment: See the answer below. Please post message of the exception you are getting in WCF client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding the service reference this way, each generated message contract is decorated in similar way as following one:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[GeneratedCode( "System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0" )]
[MessageContract( WrapperName = "GetCourseList", WrapperNamespace = "urn:CoursesIntf-ICourses",
    IsWrapped = true )]
public partial class GetCourseListRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember( Namespace = "", Order = 0 )]
    public string licence;

    public GetCourseListRequest()
    {
    }

    public GetCourseListRequest( string licence )
    {
        this.licence = licence;
    }
}
```

Each generated operation contract is decorated in similar way as following one:

```
[GeneratedCode( "System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0" )]
[ServiceContract( ConfigurationName = "ServiceReferences.ICourses" )]
public interface ICourses
{
    [OperationContract( Action = "urn:CoursesIntf-ICourses#GetCourseList", ReplyAction = "*" )]
    [XmlSerializerFormat( Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults = true,
        Use = OperationFormatUse.Encoded )]
    [ServiceKnownType( typeof( TCourse ) )]
    GetCourseListResponse GetCourseList( GetCourseListRequest request );

    // Remaining operation contracts omitted
}
```

Check the `Reference.cs` to determine whether your message and operation contracts are decorated same way. If they are, the issue lies elsewhere. Exception message would be helpful to track down the issue (e.g. it may be the order of elements in returned SOAP message).

Comment: I'm accepting this because I asked the wrong question, but this is the answer to that question.

Comment: Well, it turns out to be that the Delphi service, though configured for rpc style, was sending the elements in an order that my WCF component could not understand. (Heck, I'm still trying to understand what is being sent back).  As I get more clarity, I'll update this comment thread.

Comment: @Irwin: See [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) on how to implement `IClientMessageInspector` and `IEndpointBehavior`. The reply message from Delphi service can be viewed in `AfterReceiveReply` method. There you can reformat your message as well in order for your WCF component to be able to deserialize the reply message.